# GridView Validation is not working properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview

I want to validate on button click that at least one of the rows must be edited and updated in JavaScript.

So I wrote the below code for validation

```
function checkGridValidate() {
        var StrPriError = "";

        var grdCount = GrdProspective1.Rows.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < grdCount; i++) {

            if (GrdProspective1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value == "" || GrdProspective1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Value == "") {
                StrPriError += "Kindly edit atleast one row \n";
            }
            if (StrPriError != "") {
                alert(StrPriError);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

What happening here is, when I update the first row and submit it is not giving any alert that's perfect, but when I update the second row it still asks me *Kindly edit at least one row*.

I don't know what's going wrong here.

Have a  look the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtpkof5n/1/) for the same

Comment: Aren't you using loop variable "i" in indexing Rows collection ? I don't see that in your code. So what it does is, always looking at the first row.

Comment: @MaheshChavda: tried with that too, still it is giving me validation error if I update values for second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the validation is limited to only check the top row for two reasons:

- `.Rows[0]` will always inspect the top row, despite the `for` loop.

  This should make use of `i` as it increments through the collection:

  ```
  if (GrdProspective1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value == "" ||
  ```
- The last `if..else`, by `return`ing in either case, will interrupt the loop. The `return` statements here have a similar effect to `break` statements, with regards to the loop.

  So, unless you want the loop to be interrupted, they should be moved out the loop:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < grdCount; i++) {
      if (...) {
          // ...
      }
  }

  if (StrPriError != "") {
      alert(StrPriError);
      return false;
  }
  else {
      return true;
  }
  ```

---

Though, fixing those should reveal a different issue – the function is checking that every row has been edited rather than one-or-more.

If, for example, there are 5 rows and you fill in both fields in 2 of the rows, the remaining 3 rows will match the condition and append the error message.

Inverting the condition, so you're searching for a row that's filled in and remembering whether you have, should resolve this.

```
function checkGridValidate() {
    // assume invalid until found otherwise
    var anyEdited = false;

    var grdCount = GrdProspective1.Rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < grdCount; i++) {
        var cells = GrdProspective1.Rows[i].Cells;

        // verify that both fields were given a value
        if (cells[5].Value !== "" && cells[7].Value !== "") {

            anyEdited = true; // remember that you've found an edited row
            break;            // and, no need to keep looking for more
        }
    }

    // alert only if no rows were filled out
    if (!anyEdited) {
        alert("Kindly edit at least one row.");
    }

    return anyEdited;
}
```

Comment: let me try and check.

Comment: when I directly submit the form without updating any row. it still gets submitted. tried with this code. https://jsfiddle.net/e8o5mcyo/

Comment: tried with your updated code, I still get alert when I update the second row of the gridview

Comment: @coder Sorry. Had the wrong operators in the snippet.

Comment: @coder It wasn't entirely inverted – still had `==` instead of `!==`.

Comment: ohh. finally. It took 2 days to resolved. thanks a lot :)